# Using JSOUP to get values from websites

Tags: android, html, asp.net, jsoup

I have been trying to get the winning numbers from [Singapore Pools Lottery](http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/toto/Pages/results.aspx). 
This is my code:

```
public class getlatestWinningNumberAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        Document doc2 = null;
        Elements TestEle = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/toto/Pages/results.aspx").get();
                TestEle = doc2.select("table.table-striped");

                Log.e("TestEle", String.valueOf(TestEle));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: can you be more specific? What are you struggling with?

Comment: @luksch I kept getting the false values from the website source code. Most probably is due to the website generating the values by a script or something. How do i get the generated values instead of those from the source codes?

Comment: try this `String.valueOf(testEle tr.win1) + String.valueOf(testEle tr.win2) + String.valueOf(testEle tr.win3) + String.valueOf(testEle tr.win4) + String.valueOf(testEle tr.win5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the old drawings are loaded via an AJAX call. I looked at the network trafffic and it appears that this URL is called:

```
http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/DataFileArchive/Lottery/Output/toto_result_top_draws_en.html?v=2015y8m18d14h30m
```

the v parameter seems to give the date and time  of the drawling. If you want to use Jsoup, then you should figure out the v parameter correctly and call teh above mentioned URL with Jsoup.